# Fixed scale elements on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, notifications

I'm currently writing a Javascript plugin that needs to display an accordion notification (the sort that slide down from the top of the screen).

It works beautifully on desktop browsers simply with this css on the modals and accordions.

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work so well on mobile browsers like Android and iOS.  The default behaviour on my Galaxy S2 with Android 4 ICS is that the fixed position elements position in the correct place, and size to 100% screen width.  Unfortunately, as soon as you pinch zoom and change the scale of the page, the browser doesn't seem to recalculate the 100% width and the element goes off-screen.  Panning the content doesn't pan the fixed elements.

I found [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4), a Javascript plugin which looks to do exactly what I want - except it needs the source of the main content of the page to be changed in order to work.  My plug in has to work on **any site** and so unfortunately this isn't an option.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What does your viewport meta tag look like?

Comment: The browser does not recalculate the width because by zooming in you want to display only a part of the page. Adjusting element widths wouldn't make any sense. I've played around with your problem and came to no css-only solution that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

to your head which should stop the mobile browser from resizing the content.